# when converting python to exe : code signature invalid for

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller, signature

so I have a simple code that create a graphical interface with Tkinter on python, but when I convert it to exe using PyInstaller I get this issue , I don't understand what's happening

```
 Error loading Python lib '/Users/salwafakhir/dist/app/Python': dlopen: dlopen(/Users/salwafakhir/dist/app/Python, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Users/salwafakhir/dist/app/Python: code signature invalid for '/Users/salwafakhir/dist/app/Python'
```

here is a part of the code

```
creer une premiere fenetre 
masterWindow= Tk()
#personnaliser ma fenetre
masterWindow.title("logistics interface")
masterWindow.geometry("1280x1024")
masterWindow.minsize(480 , 360)
masterWindow.config(background='white')

#creer frame
frameProduct_1W=Frame(masterWindow,bg='white')
image = PhotoImage(file="/Users/salwafakhir/Desktop/seaver-sangle-connecte-equitation-technologie.png")
label = Label(image=image)
label.pack(expand=YES)
#ajouter un premier texte
Label_title =Label(frameProduct_1W,text="Welcome to  SeaverLogictec",font=("Time New Roman",40),bg='white',     fg="#3A67C1").pack(expand=YES)
 ajouter un second texte
Label_subtitle =Label(frameProduct_1W,text="We are here to help you with Stock management and order placing ",font=("Time New Roman",15),bg='white', fg="#3A67C1").pack(expand=YES)
#connection a la base de donne logistic
conn = MongoClient() 
db = conn.admin
#ajouter un premier bouton
startButton= Button(frameProduct_1W,text="Let's get started",font=("Time New Roman",40),bg='white', fg='#3A67C1', command=open).pack(expand=YES)
#ajouter frameProduct_1W
frameProduct_1W.pack(expand=YES)
#afficher
masterWindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you show your code too?

Comment: @CoolCloud just edited the post with part of the code

Comment: It could mean the image is no longer found? What happens when you normally run the code

Comment: it works and even when I take the picture off I still get the error

Comment: Of course, taking the picture off will give the error, why would you include a picture, if it is meant to be taken off?

Comment: no, like I. tried without the picture and it didn't work, but I don't. normal take it off

Comment: Are you sure your opening the exe inside of `dist` ?

Comment: yes, I am , i manage. to open it on a. linux but not on my Mac I need it. in my Mac

Comment: mac? i thought mac cannot run exe files, dont they have dmg? and py2app is for mac complier i believe